# Check for null values in LINQ to datatable

Tags: c#, linq

My Linq query is some thing like this:

```
IEnumerable<Results> subResult = from query in datatable.AsEnumerable()
                              select new Results
                                  {
                                      Name = query.Field<string>("Name"),
                                      Date = query.Field<DateTime?>("Date")
                                  }
```

in this one, there are some nulls coming into 'Name' field and how can I set it to zero if there is any `null`. 
How it can be done?

Comment: That's not valid C# btw; perhaps you meant `select` and not `where`.

Comment: This looks not valid code for C#..

Comment: Did you make any attempt to actually put the code that you're trying to use into your query?  LINQ is quite powerful.  You can use any expression you want to determine the result of the `Name` property.

Answer (score 4):

use the ?? operator

```
IEnumerable<Results> subResult = from query in datatable.AsEnumerable()
                              select new Results
                              {
                                  Name = query.Field<string>("Name")?? string.Empty,
                                  Date = query.Field<DateTime?>("Date")
                              }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the coalesce operator? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

something like:

```
Name = query.Field<string>("Name") ?? "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me. You may try this.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
        datatable.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
            {
               new DataColumn("Name",typeof(System.String)),
               new DataColumn("Date",typeof(System.DateTime))
            });

        datatable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Sam", DateTime.Now });
        datatable.Rows.Add(new object[] { null, DateTime.Now });

        IEnumerable<Results> subResult = from query in datatable.AsEnumerable()
                                         select new Results
                                             {
                                                 Name = query.Field<string>("Name") ?? "0" ,
                                                 Date = query.Field<DateTime?>("Date")
                                             };
    }
}

class Results
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```